# How to load a JS lib that defines a global and depends on another 3rd party lib using RquireJS?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs

I am trying to load KnockoutFire, a KnockoutJS plugin using RequireJS. It is only 1 file: https://github.com/hiroshi/knockoutFire/blob/master/knockoutFire.js

The plugin does two things:

1. Defines the global var "KnockoutFire"
2. Extends the core KnockoutJS ("ko") lib

So for this lib to load properly it needs to be able to access KnockoutJS through the global var "ko". Problem is I am loading KnockoutJS using proper AMD and there is no global "ko" available for KnockoutFire to reference. I have tried shimming both libs and various other tricks to get it to work, but I am stumped. Everything produces the error:

```
ReferenceError: ko is not defined
```

Here is what I am working with:

```
require.config({
    enforceDefine: false,
    baseUrl: 'assets/js/',
    paths: {
        'knockout': '//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-2.2.1'
    },
    shim: {
        'knockout': { exports: 'ko' },
        'knockoutfire': { exports: 'KnockoutFire', deps: ['knockout'] }
    },
    waitSeconds : 15
});


require(['knockoutfire'], function() {
    log(KnockoutFire);
});
```

I've tried doing weird stuff too like:

```
require(['knockout'], function(ko) {
    require(['knockoutfire'], function(kofire, ko) {
        log(KnockoutFire);
    });
});
```

Or:

```
define(['knockout'], function(ko) {
    require(['knockoutfire'], function(ko) {
        log(KnockoutFire);
    });
});
```

If I download the third party lib and add this to it:

```
define(['knockout'], function(ko) {
    <!--- third party lib --->
});
```

everything works fine.

Is there a way to achieve the same result without having to modify the third party lib?

Answer (score 2):

When you need these scripts use order! plugin http://requirejs.org/docs/1.0/docs/api.html#order to ensure you load knockout before knockoutfire. i.e. in ***your*** file :

```
define('require','exports','order!knockout','order!knockoutfire',
         function(req,exp,knockout,knockoutfire){
            //trimmed
```

Comment: I just tried that to no avail. I think the issue is that "ko" is never made a global regardless of order. I updated my question, see the end. Basically if I just wrap this: "define(['knockout'], function(ko) {" around the lib, everything works as it should. Is there any way to fake that in RequireJS without modifying the lib?

Comment: @Baz You need to use shims to make a file that is not aware of requirejs magically aware of requirejs without modifying the file. See my video tutorial: http://youtu.be/4AGQpv0MKsA?t=4m25s

Answer (score 2):

I think a closer look at http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-2.2.1.debug.js might reveal the answer. There is special AMD handling, and I'm not sure that's playing well with the things I've tried (using shim and exports).

This hack works though. We basically control the globals assignments with a `bootstrap` module.

```
require.config({
    enforceDefine: false,
    baseUrl: 'assets/js/',
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1',
        'knockout': 'http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/knockout-2.2.1.debug',
        'knockoutfire': 'https://raw.github.com/hiroshi/knockoutFire/master/knockoutFire'
    },
    waitSeconds: 15
});

define("bootstrap", ['jquery', 'knockout'], function ($, ko) {
    console.log("bootstrap", "jQuery " + $.fn.jquery, ko);
    window.ko = ko;
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    require(['knockoutfire'], function (kof) {
        dfd.resolve(KnockoutFire);
    });
    return dfd.promise();
});

require(['bootstrap'], function (bootstrap) {
    bootstrap.then(function () {
        console.log("ko", ko, "KnockoutFire", KnockoutFire);
    });
});
```

Outputs:

```
bootstrap jQuery 1.9.1  Object {exportSymbol: function, exportProperty: function, version: "2.2.1", utils: Object, cleanNode: function…}
ko  Object {exportSymbol: function, exportProperty: function, version: "2.2.1", utils: Object, cleanNode: function…}
KnockoutFire  Object {version: "0.0.3", utils: Object, observable: function, mapObservable: function}
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddlegrimbo/Yjgzc/6/).

Comment: Wow, that's fancy! Seeing your answer got the juices flowing and I think it can be done without promises. This seems to work:

define("globalko", ['knockout'], function (ko) {
    window.ko = ko;
});

require(['knockoutfire', 'globalko'], function (kofire) {
    console.log(kofire);
});

Comment: Code got eaten so I created a dedicated answer. The KOFire guys are willing to make minor changes to better support AMD without fully committing to it - what can/should they do?

Answer (score 1):

This answer was inspired by @Paul's answer:

```
define("globalko", ['knockout'], function (ko) {
    window.ko = ko;
});

require(['knockoutfire', 'globalko'], function (kofire) {
    console.log(kofire);
});
```

This loads both libs without error.

Anyone have any suggestions for KO or KOFire to make their libs easier to work with with AMD?

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure how that works. If `knockoutfire` loads before `globalko` then there will be an error. It might just be chance (or the fact that it's an inline define and not a remote JS request - therefore almost certain to be executed before knockoutfire) that means that solution works. My use of a Deferred *guarantees* it.

Comment: I think the basic issue is knockout is smart about how it loads, and knockoutfire is not. If you imported knockout as a `<script>` and not via AMD then knockoutfire would work, as the global `ko` would have been set.

Comment: Think knockoutfire could be fixed by putting the same magic AMD loader stuff around its content, and adding knockout as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have something like following in knockoufire

```
define('require','exports','ko',function(req,exp,ko){
//trimmed
```

Try the following line on top of knockoutfire:

```
var ko = ko.ko
```

Comment: I am trying not to have to modify 3rd party libs.